# Why error does not translated into model when i use ngModel.$setValidity?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have problem with nested directives and translating error into model

Here is the exact sample http://jsfiddle.net/mazhekin/xUS5X/12/

```
.directive('myTestValidation', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                console.log('my-test-validation link');
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    // why does the error lose (see result window)?
                    console.log('myTestError to false');
                    ngModel.$setValidity('myTestError', false);
                    return viewValue;
                });

            }
        };
    }
])
.directive('myDatepicker', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            compile: function (element, scope) {
                console.log('my-datepicker compile');
                element.removeAttr('my-datepicker');
                element.wrap('<div class="input-append"></div>');
                element.attr('my-test-validation', '');
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: but it is very strange that the code above is works in angular version 1.1.1 and does not work in next version 1.2.1. Maybe something has been corrupted in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular gathers the directives in an element (let's call it the "directive discovery" phase) and *then* calls the compilation functions; the compilation function of `myDatepicker` adds an attribute that, if present at the beginning of the process, would be interpreted as a directive. But the "directive discovery" phase is over for this element and the attribute is just an attribute.

In your case however, it is easy to remedy the situation in one of these ways:

1. The `myDatepicker` could contain the functionality of `myTestValidation`. Simplest case, use this if `myTestValidation` is not used standalone.
2. The functionality of `myTestValidation` would be exported to a service and both `myTestValidation` and `myDatepicker` will depend on this service. This is more complex, but has no code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

o.. thanks, Nikos, you pointed me to the correct way, the first advise is very useful. I resolved the issue with that way:

```
.directive('myDatepicker', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                console.log('my-test-validation link');
                element.removeAttr('my-datepicker');
                element.wrap('<div class="input-append"></div>');

                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    // cool!! the error has not been lost
                    console.log('myTestError to false');
                    ngModel.$setValidity('myTestError', true);
                    return viewValue;
                });

            }
        };
    }
]);
```